# DataTable DBNull Row Value Error

Tags: datagridview, datagrid, vb.net-2010, datarow, datacolumn

I am having a problem when refering to an item within a datarow .

When i execute the code below, my intention is to transfer a data grid view to a datatable, make comparisons with the data and execute a particular set of events, however when i run the

"***For Each PaymentRow As DataRow In dtPayments.Rows***"

line i am finding that all items within the row are "DBNull".

The code breaks at the following line

***"If PaymentRow.Item("Amount") = PaymentRow.Item("OutstandingBalance") Then"***

It errors due to the face that it cant compare two DBNull objects

I am stuck on this as i have reviewed my code countless number of times and still cant get to the bottom of it.

Thanks in advance for the help guys

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim dtPayments As New DataTable

    For Each dgColumn As DataGridViewColumn In dgvInvoices.Columns
        Dim dc As New DataColumn
        dc.ColumnName = dgColumn.Name
        dc.DataType = dgColumn.ValueType
        dtPayments.Columns.Add(dc)
    Next

    For Each dgRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvInvoices.Rows

        Dim drow As DataRow = dtPayments.NewRow
        For Each dCell As DataGridViewCell In dgRow.Cells
            If dCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Amount" Then
                If IsDBNull(dCell.Value) Then
                    drow.Item(dCell.OwningColumn.Name) = 0.0
                Else
                    drow.Item(dCell.OwningColumn.Name) = dCell.Value
                End If
            Else
                drow.Item(dCell.OwningColumn.Name) = dCell.Value
            End If
        Next

        dtPayments.Rows.Add(dgRow)


    Next


    For Each PaymentRow As DataRow In dtPayments.Rows

        Dim strInvoiceRef As String = PaymentRow.Item("InvoiceRef").ToString


        If PaymentRow.Item("Amount") = PaymentRow.Item("OutstandingBalance") Then
            CreateDebit(PaymentRow.Item("Amount"), strInvoiceRef)
            CropTrackMod.PaidInvoiceHeader(strInvoiceRef, True)
            Dim dtTicketsOnInvoice As DataTable = CropTrackMod.GetDistinctTicketsOnInvoice(strInvoiceRef)
            For Each DistinctRow As DataRow In dtTicketsOnInvoice.Rows
                'set this list to paid
                CropTrackMod.PaidTicket(DistinctRow.Item("TicketRef").ToString(), True)

            Next
        ElseIf PaymentRow.Item("AmountPaid") < PaymentRow.Item("OutstandingBalance") Then
            CreateDebit(PaymentRow.Item("Amount"), strInvoiceRef)
        End If


    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking "Amount", check if "OutstandingBalance" is DBNull when you loop through the rows. That way it will also be set to 0.0 so your comparison later on is valid:

```
For Each dgRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvInvoices.Rows
        Dim drow As DataRow = dtPayments.NewRow
        For Each dCell As DataGridViewCell In dgRow.Cells
            If dCell.OwningColumn.Name = "Amount" Or dCell.OwningColumn.Name = "OutstandingBalance" Then
                etc.
```

Comment: both the PaymentRow("Amount") and the PaymentRow("OutstandingBalance") are showing as dbnull depite checking "Amount". "OutstandingBalance" is taken from a database and always has a value.

Comment: PaymentRow("Amount") is DBNull when you do the comparison?

Are you setting the datasource of dgvInvoices programatically? If so, has dgvInvoices had DataBind() called by the time this handler fires?

Comment: yes amount and outstanding is db null when compared. I am passing the structure and values from a DataGridView to a new data table and then looping through each row in the data table. No DataBind() has taken place